# Getting Error Accessing Certain IBM Connections Blog using IBM Social Business Toolkit SDK via Java: SBT context is not initialized for the request

Tags: java, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I have a Java agent in a Domino database to read blog posts from an on-premisis IBM Connections 4.5 installation using the Social Business Tooklit SKD.  The java agent is able to access several test blogs and retrieve the list of blog posts, but other blogs in the same environment are generating the following error:

HTTP JVM: com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientServicesException: SBT context is not initialized for the request

The error is being thrown on the following line:

Blog bo = blogService.getBlog(bRef.getId());

All of the blogs are accessible directly via a browser, and the Java agent can access some of the blogs, but consistently throws this error when attempting to get a handle to others.  I have been unable to identify any differences in the setup or access restrictions of the blogs.  Does anybody have any ideas on where to look?

Here is the stack trace for the error:

02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM: :: syncBlog(a8db5539-6187-40e9-9d87-d182b5b3280c)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM: com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientServicesException: SBT context is not initialized for the request
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.BaseService.getEntity(BaseService.java:204)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.blogs.BlogService.getBlogEntity(BlogService.java:667)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.blogs.BlogService.getBlog(BlogService.java:393)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.triloggroup.connections.filesync.SynchronizationEngine.syncBlog(SynchronizationEngine.java:555)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.triloggroup.connections.filesync.SynchronizationEngine.syncBlogs(SynchronizationEngine.java:453)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.triloggroup.connections.filesync.SynchronizationEngine.run(SynchronizationEngine.java:229)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:17)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM: Caused by:
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SBT context is not initialized for the request
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.commons.runtime.Context.get(Context.java:57)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.endpoints.BasicEndpoint.authenticate(BasicEndpoint.java:151)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.forceAuthentication(ClientService.java:314)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.processResponse(ClientService.java:1311)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService._xhr(ClientService.java:1229)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.execRequest(ClientService.java:1194)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.xhr(ClientService.java:1151)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.get(ClientService.java:1012)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.get(ClientService.java:1008)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.BaseService.retrieveData(BaseService.java:391)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.BaseService.retrieveData(BaseService.java:414)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.BaseService.retrieveData(BaseService.java:367)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.BaseService.getEntity(BaseService.java:201)
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM:      ... 8 more
02/24/2015 12:05:17 AM  HTTP JVM: :: term()

Comment: Check to see that you have created an Endpoint object.  the BasicEndpoint can then be passed in an used as the context.

Comment: The process works fine with some blogs but not with others.  What we have determined is that the ID we use to authenticate the connection needs to be the blog owner for it to work.  If the ID is just a member of the blog we get the context error.  I will add the stack trace to the original post.

Comment: I'd encourage you to post that as the response.

Comment: Thank you for the responses @Paul-Bastide.  I wasn't able to post the stack trace as a response because it was too long. However, I did add it to my original post above.

Comment: Check your username and password... are they correct?

Comment: Yes, verified the credentials.  I can use them to log in via the web interface and view each of the blogs.  The agent is able to use those credentials with the SDK to successfully connect to two of the blogs where that user is the owner.  Only when it tries to access the third blog where the owner is someone else does it generate the error.  We were able to access the third blog via the SDK if we changed the owner, but this isn't a realistic solution for production.  BTW, these are stand alone blogs not part of any communities.

Comment: add this to your java agent static {
  
  /*
   * Apache Http Client Debug Parameters
   */
  System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log",
    "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
  System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime",
    "true");
  
  // Change DEBUG to INFO and back
  System.setProperty(
    "org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire",
    "DEBUG");

 }  and then carefully post the content (it may include auth headers), we can look at it here